# How to create tally marks / hash marks with LaTeX

Tags: tables, symbols

[image]

Hi

I want to add a column in my table like the given image.
How to produce this type of difficult symbol in latex?

Comment: Loading the `cancel` package, and writing things like `\bcancel{\mahsf{III}}` should do the trick.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tally_marks, the "difficult symbols" are called "tally marks" or "hash marks".